# php for loop inside a foreach loop, not sure how to do it

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying to do a for loop inside a foreach loop.

I have a table in my database as follows:

```
ID        | Fname | Lname
------------------------
1          Bart    Simpson
1          Mickey  Mouse
2          Peter   Griffin
2          Clark   Kenet
2          David   Johnson
```

i call the data from the database (and it works, tested on phpmyadmin), I want the data to be shown on the page by the `ID` value for exemple:

Bart Simpson, Mickey  Mouse & Peter   Griffin

Clark Kenet & David   Johnson

as you see there in an "&"  before the last name at any row but that isnt my problem.

this is the code i wrote:

```
//HERE I RETRIVE ALL THE DATA FROM THE DATABASE.
$query = $dbh->query(" SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE ID= '{$ID}'
        ");   

//THIS CODE SHOWS THE NUMBER OF ROWS WITH THE CURRENT ID 
        $sql    = "SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM table WHERE ID= '{$ID}'";
        $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();

//THIS IS THE FOREACH IN WHICH I CALL ALL THE ROWS BY THEIR VALUE
          foreach ($query as  $key =>$value) {
                   $value['wFname'][$key] = !empty($value['wFname'][$key]) ? $value['wFname'][$key] : '';                      
$numRow = $number_of_rows-2; // THE ITEM BEFORE THE LAST ONE IN THE ARRAY
$lastItem = $number_of_rows-1; //LAST INDEX IN THE ARRAY
for($counter = 0; $counter = $numRow; $counter++){
 return  $value['wLname'][$counter] . ', '.  $value['wFname'][$counter];
  }
   return  "&" . $value['wLname'][$lastItem] . ', '.$value['wFname'][$lastItem] ;
   return ' ';

                };
```

with this code i get only the first pair of names with each id.
any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
for($counter = 0; $counter = $numRow; $counter++){
```

to:

```
for($counter = 0; $counter =< $numRow; $counter++){
```

You are checking if $counter equals $numRow, and you should check if it equals and is less than...

Hope this helps.

## EDIT Based on user requests

Try storing the results in a variable and return that variable at the end of both loops, but im not sure what you are trying to achieve here, try running the following code:

```
//HERE I RETRIVE ALL THE DATA FROM THE DATABASE.
        $query = $dbh->query(" SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE ID= '{$ID}'
        ");

//THIS CODE SHOWS THE NUMBER OF ROWS WITH THE CURRENT ID 
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM table WHERE ID= '{$ID}'";
        $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();

//THIS IS THE FOREACH IN WHICH I CALL ALL THE ROWS BY THEIR VALUE
        $return = "";
        foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
            $value['wFname'][$key] = !empty($value['wFname'][$key]) ? $value['wFname'][$key] : '';
            $numRow = $number_of_rows - 2; // THE ITEM BEFORE THE LAST ONE IN THE ARRAY
            $lastItem = $number_of_rows - 1; //LAST INDEX IN THE ARRAY
            for ($counter = 0; $counter <= $numRow; $counter++) {
                $return .= $value['wLname'][$counter] . ', ' . $value['wFname'][$counter];
            }
            $return .= "&" . $value['wLname'][$lastItem] . ', ' . $value['wFname'][$lastItem];
            $return .= ' ';
        }
        return $return;
```

Comment: TNX, not anging anyting, i dont get wy i dont see te last result

Comment: Thats because your return statement, instead of returning in the for loop you should assign the value to a variable and then show it when the loops ends after the curly braces.

Comment: tnx, the foreach is a part of a method, thats why it is assignd in return

Comment: Yes, but at soon the code reaches the return, the method will stop executing the for loop.

Comment: didn't knew tat retun kills a for loop. tnx! I chaged the return inside the loop but nothing changed, still see only te fisrt pair of names

Comment: You have 2 more return statements in your code that are breaking the foreach loop as well :)

Comment: i must be returned becouse it is inside a function, can you please suggest some other answer?

Comment: Maybe the call from the database should be with fech_something?