# php array output with for loop dosent come as it should

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to retrive data from database using `FECH_ASSOC` in order the output will took like this

last1 first1 last2 first2 & last3 first3

last4 first4 & last4 first4

this is the database i have:

```
ID  index  first    last
--------------------------
1     1    first1   last1  
2     1    first2   last2  
3     1    first3   last3  
4     2    first4   last4  
5     2    first5   last5
```

Each output row shoud defined by the index value.
as you can see in the output example I need the organ before the last one in any array to be separetad because i need to put the  `&` before it.

this is the code i came up with:

```
//HERE I RETRIVE ALL THE DATA FROM THE DATABASE.
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM table WHERE index= $index";
        $result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();
        $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();

//ASSOC DEFINITION
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE index= $index);
    $sth->execute();
    $value = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//THIS IS WHERE I CALL ALL THE ROWS BY THEIR VALUE
    $return = "";
                $fname                = $value['fname'];
                $lname                = $value['lname'];
                $numRow = $number_of_rows-2;   // THE ITEM BEFORE THE LAST ONE IN THE ARRAY
                $lastItem = $number_of_rows - 1; //LAST INDEX IN THE ARRAY
                    for($counter = 0; $counter <= $numRow; $counter++){
                    $value = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                 
                        $fname[$counter] = !empty($fname[$counter]) ? $fname[$counter] : '';

                    $return .= $lname. ', ' .   $fname;
                    }
                   $fname[$counter] = !empty($fname[$lastItem]) ? $fname[$lastItem] : '';

                    $return .= "&" . $fname. ', ' . $lname;
                    $return .= ' ';

            return $return;
```

this is the output i get:
last3 first1 last1 first1 & last2 first1

last5 first4 & last4 first4

I cant figure out what i am doing wrong.
I tryied using foreach but i didnt manage to separete the last pair of values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900938/php-for-loop-inside-a-foreach-loop-not-sure-how-to-do-it/28900972#28900972).

I am stuck with this this for a few days.
any help would be great.

Comment: Which type of output you want can you explain more ?

Comment: this is what i want to get line1-   last1 first1 last2 first2 & last3 first3.
line 2- last4 first4 & last4 first4.  and so on

Comment: For managing this type of output i think you are required to manage the flags which will produce the output according to your requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by saying flags? Do you mean keys?

Comment: No Keys I means you have maintain flags like for example if x==1 it will display the array values till last1 first1 last2 first2 & last3 first3 and then we have to check  for the next outcomes i.e. x==2 and so on . like this we have loop the database.

Comment: Hey, I can't find a tutorial that explains the php flags issue. could you supply some link?  tnx

Comment: Why not just add an order by clause in the select query? 
`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE index= $index ORDER BY ID"`